# On the Risk of EV Fires

Tags: batteries

I'm wondering about the safety of parking EV automobiles in under our 50 condo units. One question is whether all EV cars are UL approved. Several have caught on fire w/o being in an accident.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's unrelated to this stack.

Comment: @Davide Assessment of risk from fire or other hazards relating to electrical systems ought to be on-topic for an electrical engineering forum.

Comment: SAE is responsible for setting most standards, and their electric vehicle group is *really good*.  DOT and NHTSA are responsible for enforcing safety standards. Almost all of the world's automakers have engineering departments in metro Detroit, so they participate in SAE.  If an unqualified automaker tries to sell cars here, GM/Ford lawyers will be working with DOT/NHTSA to get them blocked.

Comment: Perhaps the question should be reworded something like, "What are the risks of fire for EVs parked under a residential building, how have these risks been addressed, and what further design changes could minimize these risks?" Hopefully the OP can make similar changes so that the question might deserve re-opening.

Answer (score 6):

First, let's step back and get some perspective here. [Vehicle fires in the US per year](https://www.familyhandyman.com/article/are-electric-vehicles-more-likely-to-catch-on-fire/):

- ICE: 1,530 per 100,000 vehicles
- EV: 25 per 100,000 vehicles

So, if anything, you should be concerned about the 99 ICE cars in your condo, not the 1 EV.

Second: UL standards do not apply to vehicles, and, in any case UL is a private company: its approval is not required by the US. Other standards do apply. In the case of EV batteries, one standard that applies is UN 38.3.

Comment: An [article](https://www.ctif.org/news/150-000-liters-water-needed-put-out-fire-electric-car) and our local fire chief states that it takes about 8000 to 40000 gallons of water to put out an EV fire, about 500 to 1000 gallons for an ICE fire.

Comment: Davide--Thank you for thoughts. UL does approve batteries for small EV vehicles. I'm wondering about larger ones. As to fires, Fire Departments are trained and equipped to handle gasoline fires in automobiles. EV's are more like explosions than fires. GM advised not to park Volt EV's inside. I'm looking for someone who is up on UL or any other documentation of safety for EV cars.

Comment: @All - I have removed comments which crossed the line into *ad hominem* attacks. Remember that those break the [Code of Conduct](/help/conduct). As the CoC says (amongst many other things): "Focus on the content, not the person." Don't make accusations about someone's intentions / agenda / etc. || Please be careful with any future comments and remember, the Code of Conduct says: "If a situation makes it hard to be friendly, stop participating and move on." Thanks.

Comment: @qrk, so on average ICE vehicles take slightly more water, spread over more instances, once Firefighters are all equipped with car sized fire blankets, water usage should decrease.